# Can Selenium WebDriver (java) interact with the Browser's inspect tool element selector?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector, chrome-devtools-protocol

By using selenium, can I access the browsers element picker (Ctrl + Shift + C, in the browser) that is located in the inspect tab?

I want to "point" to an element using that picker and have it be high lighted in the browser.

For example, something simple like:

`WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("userName"));
elem.pointer();`

and that would show the element as highlighted/selected in the browser, same was the inspect tab works. [image: Example Image]

Comment: It's unlikely that this is possible since the driver generally can't access browser-specific actions/UI. You can inject CSS into the element to do things like put a red border around the element, etc. Google "selenium highlight element" and you'll find a number of examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660291/highlight-elements-in-webdriver-during-runtime)

Comment: As far as I know, chrome doesn't provide such api in its driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially **Yes**. Using [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) you will be able to interact with the [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) API using the *Java* client soon.

Integration of the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) is still in *WIP (Work In Progress)* and @AdiOhana have recently [contributed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/7212) for the [Network](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network) and [Performance](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance) domains for a better user facing API.

In the discussion [Controlling Chrome Devtools with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790649/controlling-chrome-devtools-with-selenium-webdriver) @AdiOhana mentions of the example usage as follows:

```
    driver.getDevTools().createSession();
    driver.getDevTools().send(new Command("Profiler.enable", ImmutableMap.of()));
    driver.getDevTools().send(new Command("Profiler.start", ImmutableMap.of()));
    //register to profiler events
    driver.getDevTools().addListener(new Event("Profiler.consoleProfileStarted", ConsoleProfileStarted.class), new Consumer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Object o) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

> Note: Until the Profiler domain will added to Selenium java client, you will have to supply your Mapper.

---

### Outro

[What is the difference between WebDriver and DevTool protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939116/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-devtool-protocol/50942942#50942942)