# [Selenium 4.0.0-beta-1]: how add event listeners in CDP

Tags: python, selenium, beta, chrome-devtools-protocol

I've built and installed [Selenium 4.0.0-beta-1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/selenium-4.0.0-beta-1) python wheel from source to test [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) functionalities. Specifically I would like to intercept requests using [Fetch Domain protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/).

I can enable the domain using `Fetch.enable` command, but I don't see how I can subscribe to events like [Fetch.requestPaused](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#event-requestPaused) to intercept the request:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Enable Fetch domain
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Fetch.enable', cmd_args={})

# How to subscribe to Fetch.requestPaused event??
# driver.add_cdp_event_listener ...
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9):

Tested on selenium 4.0.0rc1, with chromedriver v94 (latest as of 9/21/2021).

```py
import trio # async library that selenium uses
from selenium import webdriver

async def start_listening(listener):
    async for event in listener:
        print(event)

async def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    async with driver.bidi_connection() as connection:
        session, devtools = connection.session, connection.devtools

        # await session.execute(devtools.fetch.enable())
        await session.execute(devtools.network.enable())

        # listener = session.listen(devtools.fetch.RequestPaused)
        listener = session.listen(devtools.network.ResponseReceived)
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            nursery.start_soon(start_listening, listener) # start_listening blocks, so we run it in another coroutine

            driver.get('https://google.com')


trio.run(main)
```

A few things to note:

- Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like `Fetch.requestPaused` works currently. `Fetch.enable` sends the command and pauses requests, but it seems like selenium never receives the `RequestPaused` event. (Which is why the code snippet is using `Network.responseReceived`)
- There is no documentation for the `devtools` class, but you can still view the source .py files for available attributes.

Update:
`Fetch.requestPaused` works now. Have a look at example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75067388/20443541
It a also supports **changing headers**.

Comment: `in main
    async with driver.log._get_bidi_connection() as session:
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'log' `
Got installed selenium v4.0.0rc1 Using pycharm also highlighting 'network' as `Unresolved attribute reference 'network' for class 'ModuleType'` at 'devtools.network' (2 usage)

Comment: @void_eater Updated the answer to work with rc1.