# Selenium 4 Python - getDevTools() not ready yet?

Tags: python, selenium

In Selenium 4 Java it is possible to write:

```java
DevTools chromeDevTools = driver.getDevTools();

...

chromeDevTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(),
        req -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Sent %s request to %s",
                    req.getRequest().getMethod(),
                    req.getRequest().getUrl()
            ));
        });
```

However, there is only `execute_cdp_cmd()` for Python. Is this feature not ready yet or I missed something?

Comment: It seems that way, at least I couldn't find anything in the documentation. This question is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420493/how-to-use-chrome-devtools-protocol-in-selenium-using-python-for-capturing-htt