# How to automate api request on website

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, automation

Overview : I have a website (ex: www.amazon.com). When I enter this website in the browser it opens up the amazon home page and now when I sniff the back end calls in fiddler/charles I get tons of these back end calls which get me the data.

Problem: Now these back end calls , I need to assert the get request of these back end calls. If the right request is fired with the right parameters or not. All of our team members currently are utilising charles or fiddler to test them manually. I am looking for a solution to some how capture all of the api requests on the fly using selenium framework and basically test this on different browsers and OS combinations.

Tried so far: I have tried using the browser mob/ little proxy to basically monitor these calls through a proxy. but none of these solutions are stable and 50 % of the time they are false failures.

Comment: What language?  Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried chrome dev tools ?  If it works for you manually, then you can use Chrome in remote debugging mode when it exposes tcp socket that can be used for interacting with the backend part of DevTools. From there you can get the various calls it is making and work on it.

take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20916035/888070) and [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol)